# Gedit inserts blank lines sporadically when using scroll wheel

Tags: 10.04, mouse, gedit, mouse-scroll

I do extensive editing of text files using gedit.  If I use the scroll wheel to move back and forth in the file, sometimes a blank line is inserted in the file.  This is not obvious when it occurs.  I discover the blank line(s) later, so I don't know where I was in the file relative to where the blank line gets inserted.  The only way I have found not to have blank lines inserted is not to use the scroll wheel.  Has anybody else noticed this behavior?  Any ideas how to get it corrected?

Comment: Could you please provide more information about your setup. What version of Ubuntu are you using and what version of Gedit? Does this happen on other systems you try or only for a particular mouse?

Comment: Sorry, I should have included that.  I'm running 10.04, with whatever version of gedit comes with it.  I use a Adesso WKB 3000 UB wireless keyboard with a trackball and scrollwheel, no mouse.  I don't see this behavior with any other program.  However, I seldom use any other program with files as large as those I use with gedit.  The files where I see this happening are anywhere from 150KB-450KB, maybe 3000-13000 lines.  I only do these operations on this one computer, not on any of my other ones, so I don't have any way to compare that.

Comment: That is more details, good. Could you please include them in your question by [editing it](http://askubuntu.com/posts/98748/edit) so that others easier see it.

Answer (score 1):

So I think what's happening is it's registering as if you're clicking the scroll wheel (which is the same as 'middle click'.  This may fix it: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input#Example:_Disabling_middle-mouse_button_paste_on_a_scrollwheel_mouse